# make bootstrap menu or sub-menu visible in left side if it's going beyond browser edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Check my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvwk8jb/2/), as you can see there are some dropdown menus,please resize the browser in a way that 'Dropdown' menu will come to right side. Then go to '2nd level menu' as you can see submenu are opening in right side, hence they are not visible fully. Although we have space in left-side, is there any way we can make sub-menu visible on left if it's going beyond screen.

How it's looking:
[image]

So this is what I want to achieve:

1. How to detect particular menus is going outside the browser edge??
2. After detection How to make it reverse aligned, so that user can see it.

How it should behave, if there is not enough space in right-side to open submenu, menus will be shown in left-side:

[image: Expexted behavior]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret">        </b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
      <li>
      <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">I can be in left side</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why i am coming on right side</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I want to come in Left side</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Enough space in left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I will not be visible as i am long</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why exactly can't you use jQuery. You have to have it loaded for Bootstrap, why not use it?

Comment: @rob even I raised the same question, but there is strict NO from client.

Comment: @rob you can answer this with jquery, I had discussion with client.. they want to see the approach..

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pull-left` if the dropdown in the right of the page: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80xcb3rv/) 
you can use some JS to make it dynamic on browser re-size, by calculating the div position

Comment: Thats how you do it, don't think there is a way without JS. Btw. this could be helpful to calculate the position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: That should be `dropdown-menu-left`; using `pull-*` to control dropdown menu directions is deprecated.